# Are collisions possible in SQL Automatic timestamps?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with a field that is an automatic timestamp field (`SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).  The field is microsecond precision.  Is it possible to have rows with the same timestamp or does PostgreSQL's concurrency control impose a serial ordering on object updates?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT : current_timestamp is tied to the begin of the transaction, so multiple rows that are inserted/updated in the same transaction wilhave the same timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Even if you use `clock_timestamp()` so you get a new timestamp each time, and even if you're on a system with microsecond timer precision, collisions are likely.

Microsecond timer precision doesn't mean microsecond timer *accuracy* or *resolution*. The clock advances in "jumps". On some systems those jumps are sub-microsecond (μs) and invisible to applications that work at microsecond timer resolutions like PostgreSQL. But on some systems they can be tens or hundreds of milliseconds (ms)!

On MS Windows prior to the introduction of [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows 8 and Server 2012 (and its adoption by PostgreSQL 9.5) time was limited to 1 millisecond (ms) resolution, and was typically 15ms resolution! So it's *extremely* likely to get the same time value for multiple calls on a system that is anything except mostly idle.

On modern Linux, or on modern Windows with recent PostgreSQL, collisions are much less likely due to sub-millisecond timer resolution. But they're definitely still possible. If you choose to use a timestamp as a unique key your app must be able to retry if it gets a unique violation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Looking at a PostgreSQL table with about 50 million entries, I am seeing about 70 sets of entries that have the same timestamp in an automatic timestamp field.